# do you know of any python component(s) for syntax highlighting?

Tags: python, components, syntax-highlighting

Are there any easy to use python components that could be used in a GUI? It would be great to have something like JSyntaxPane for Python. I would like to know of python-only versions ( not interested in jython ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using gtk+, there's a binding of gtksourceview for Python in [gnome-python-extras](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-python-extras/2.25/).  It seems to work well in my experience.  The downside:  the documentation is less than perfect.

There's also a binding of [QScintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro) for Python if PyQt is your thing.

Answer (score 9):

Other than pygments?  http://pygments.org/

Comment: how could I make use of pygments in a GUI application?

Comment: Pygments can output to HTML or RTF. Just use a GUI widget that can render either of those.

Comment: Could you post a link to a widget that can render html?

Comment: Also it's not particularly hard to hack a Pango outputter for putting Pygments output straight into GTK Widgets.

Comment: You could also write a custom formatter to output syntax highlighting in whatever format your widget needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StyledTextCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html) in [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org). Check out the official demo for an example (The *demo code* tab for any demo).

Answer (score 0):

You say "in a GUI app" but don't mention the toolkit.

If you are using PyQt, and need a read-only widget, you can use QWebKit which has a whole HTML widget in it based on WebKit, so it supports pretty much anything, from flash to the ACID2 test.

If you want a read-write widget, Qt's QTextEdit supports syntax highlighting, and I wrote an adapter to let pygments worj with it:

http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/2009/09/21.html#BB831

I am sure something similar can be done with other toolkits, but I don't know how.